# Чи завжди прийменник "в" вимовляється як "ў"?

Tags: фонетика

В мене є сумніви у випадках, коли наступне слово починається с голосної, наприклад, `"в Україні"`. Чи має в таких випадках `"в"` вимовлятися як `"ў"` (нескладотворче `"у"`), або так, як `"в"` вимовляється у слові `"вулиця"`?